# Title Explanation of the movie "The Pale Blue Eye"

Tags: title, the-pale-blue-eye

Why has the movie "The Pale Blue Eye" the title "The Pale Blue Eye"? What does the title mean, what does the title refer to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The title refers to a line from Edgar Allan Poe's [The Tell-Tale Heart.](https://poemuseum.org/the-tell-tale-heart/)

> It is impossible to say how first the idea entered my brain; but once conceived, it haunted me day and night. Object there was none. Passion there was none. I loved the old man. He had never wronged me. He had never given me insult. For his gold I had no desire. **I think it was his eye! yes, it was this! One of his eyes resembled that of a vulture — a pale blue eye, with a film over it**. Whenever it fell upon me, my blood ran cold; and so by degrees — very gradually — I made up my mind to take the life of the old man, and thus rid myself of the eye forever.

The movie tells the story of a murder at the West Point military academy during Edgar Allan Poe's time there as a student.